# mySql select query with combination condition of two columns

Tags: mysql

In my sample `MySql` table, I have a table `Table1` and three columns `id`, `column1` and `column2`. Here `columnn1` and `column2` has combination of records like the foreign_key from two tables. Right now I have the below query in a loop.

```
SELECT t.id FROM `Table1` t WHERE t.column1 = 'value' and t.column2 = 'value';
```

Here I will get a number of rows with a combination of column1 and column2. Is there any way to get this value for multiple column1 and column2 value combinations?

Comment: When saying *Here `columnn1` and `column2` has combination of records like the foreign_key from two tables* Do you mean *`columnn1` and `column2` **are** foreign keys to other tables* ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `OR` with brackets between various `AND` combinations.

Try the following:

```
SELECT t.id FROM `Table1` t 
WHERE (t.column1 = 'value' and t.column2 = 'value') 
                  OR  
      (t.column1 = 'value2' and t.column2 = 'value2')
                  OR  
      (t.column1 = 'value3' and t.column2 = 'value3')
                  OR  
      (t.column1 = 'value4' and t.column2 = 'value4')
```

... and so on